# Launch activity from google calendar reminders

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api, android-launcher

I'm new to Android development and I would like to create an app that can launch a scheduled activity reminders from Google calendar.

I tried to do it with filters intents and it does not work, and I searched unsuccessfully for code examples.

Below is what I've done so far. This code is part of a manifest.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="MasReceiver" >

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER" />

    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the system can't find MasReceiver. The name you supply for your broadcast receiver in the  element has to be fully qualified. The [documentation for the receiver element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) explains this in more detail.